# Negative lookahead with awk or sed not possible but only perl supports

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have text which spans multiple lines

```
    ... someabove text

  jpqpq====== mcvnmcv

    .... s;ql[[pw]]

    <<<<<< uyuuey

    ... middle text

  jhasjh  ======dsadsas

    .... grqywtrt

  klklk  <<<<<<alallal

    ... someend text
```

I want to remove all the text from `====== till <<<<<<`

In `sublime text` i use

find: `(?s)(======(?:(?!======).)*?<<<<<<)`

replace :

and all the occurences are removed and output looks

```
    ... someabove text

  jpqpq     uyuuey

    ... middle text

  jhasjh  alallal

    ... someend text
```

Now i want to do this using command line using `sed or awk or anything`. Because everytime to open the file and do replace is tedious

But i searched for sed and awk, i found that they dont support non zero regex. and perl is used in these cases

Can someone confirm that sed and awk cant use such patterns like this `(======(?:(?!======).)*?<<<<<<)` and have to try some indirect ways.

Still i am looking for how to do this with sed and awk (even indirect) and also perl (if lookahead is allowed)

with perl also it didnt work

```
perl -ne 's/"(======(?:(?!======).)*?<<<<<<)"/""/g; print' file
```

blank output

Comment: That perl command works just need a small change `perl -n0e 's/(?s)(======(?:(?!======).)*?<<<<<<)//g; print' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, neither awk nor sed support lookarounds. More specifically, the regex flavors they use don't support them.

Your perl command failed because you need to tell it that this is a multiline string (the `s`) modifier. But that would still fail because `perl` reads input line by line, and would apply the replacement operator to each line. If you want it to match across the entire file, you need to slurp it with `-0777`. This does what you need:

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/======.*?<<<<<<//gs' file 
    ... someabove text

  jpqpq uyuuey

    ... middle text

  jhasjh  alallal

    ... someend text
```

The `-0777` causes perl to slurp the entire file. The `-p` makes it print each line and the `-e` gives it what you want it to do. I also simplified your regex since there seems no reason to use such a complex approach. `======.*?<<<<<<` will match `======`, then the `.*?<<<<<<` means "as few characters as possible until the `<<<<<<`. Finally, the `/sg` at the end will activate multiline strings (`s`, allowing the `.` to match newlines) and will make the replacement operator work globally (`g`) so it will replace all occurrences.

---

In `sed`, if your markers were on lines by themselves, that is if you wanted to delete everything on the `======` and `<<<<<<` lines, you could do this:

```
$ sed '/======/,/<<<<<</d' file 
    ... someabove text


    ... middle text


    ... someend text
```

But that wont' work for you here.

Comment: @ikegami indeed. I'm not arguing, I've read enough of your answers over the years not to doubt your Perl knowledge. I was just confused at first myself ([and not for the first time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192485/22222)). Also, I had always assumed that `-00` was setting `$/="\n\n"` (which it doesn't, as you said and as my test confirmed). So I guess `$/=undef` is treated the same way as `$/="\n\n"` internally? Why do they both seem to have the same result? Or should I ask a question about this instead?

Comment: `$/ = undef;` (`-0777`) causes readline to read the whole file ("slurp mode").

Comment: `$/ = "\n\n";` causes readline to return a line when it finds two subsequent line feeds or EOF.

Comment: `$/ = "";` (`-00`) causes readline to return a line when it finds 2+ subsequent line feeds or EOF ("paragraph mode").

Comment: if i have `======  ...  ====== ....  <<<<<<`  then it will remove both `======` I only want  `====== ....  <<<<<<` to be removed but not `======  ...  ====== ....  <<<<<<`

Answer (score 0):

Right you don't get looka-whatever with sed or awk but you also don't need it, it's just syntactic sugar. With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='<<<<<<' -v ORS= 'RT{sub(/======.*/,"")} 1' file
    ... someabove text

  jpqpq uyuuey

    ... middle text

  jhasjh  alallal

    ... someend text
```

and with GNU sed for `-z`:

```
$ sed -z 's/@/@A/g; s/{/@B/g; s/}/@C/g; s/======/{/g; s/<<<<<</}/g;
          s/{[^{}]*}//g;
          s/}/<<<<<</g; s/======/{/g; s/@C/}/g; s/@B/{/g; s/@A/@/g
' file
    ... someabove text

  jpqpq uyuuey

    ... middle text

  jhasjh  alallal

    ... someend text
```

Answer (score 0):

if no `<` character within ===== till <<<<< in data 'd' file, tried on gnu sed

```
sed -Ez 's/={6}[^<]*<{6}//g' d
```