# perl: regex help needed to replace text within two words with certain conditions

Tags: regex, perl

This question seems to be the same as [Negative lookahead with awk or sed not possible but only perl supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744007/negative-lookahead-with-awk-or-sed-not-possible-but-only-perl-supports/55814498#55814498) But its not the same.

In this question i want to know how to solve more conditions for my search

I have the following text (sample.txt)

> *Condition 1: contains PQXY in between QWWK and KWWQ so not wanted*

```
QWWK erly jointure  PQXY In said devonshire 
Drift allow green son walls years for blush.
acceptance son KWWQ
```

> *Condition 2: QWWK does not start at the beginnig of the line, so not wanted*

```
other QWWK get him his projection ar saw fat sudden edward
sociable felicity supplied mr. September
ay now many. Alte KWWQ
```

> *Condition 3: KWWQ is not at the end of the line, so not wanted*

```
QWWK ble formerly six but hand
r way now many. Alteration you 
occasion ham for  KWWQ other
```

> *Condition 4: QWWK begins at the starting and KWWQ ends at the last and there is no PQXY, so this is what wanted*

```
QWWK n zealously arranging fr
eal park so rest we on. Ignorant d
he possession insensible sympathi KWWQ
.......
```

> Kindly the note the words QWWK PQXY and KWWQ

*My text goes multiple lines.*

```
I want to match text between QWWK and KWWQ

Condition 1: should not contain the word PQXY inbetween

Condition 2: QWWK should start at the beginning of the line

Condition 3: KWWQ should be at the end of the line
```

In sublime text i match using:

```
(?s)(^QWWK(?:(?!QWWK).)*?KWWQ\n)
```

and it matches  condition 4

```
QWWK n zealously arranging fr

eal park so rest we on. Ignorant d

 he possession insensible sympathi KWWQ
```

So it does not match condition 1, condition 2 and condition 3.

I am trying with perl to replace condition 4 with sometext i am trying

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/^QWWK(?!QWWK).*?KWWQ\n/sometext/gs' sample.txt > sample_mod.txt
```

But sample_mod.txt did not replace the codition 4

I also tried

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/\nQWWK(?!QWWK).*?KWWQ\n/sometext/gs' sample.txt > sample_mod.txt
```

It removes both condition 1 and condition4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/m` alters the definition of `^` and `$` to be start of line and end of line respectively.

What you asked for:

```
/^QWWK(?:(?!PQXY).)*KWWQ$/msg
```

What you probably want:

```
/^QWWK(?:(?!QWWK|PQXY|KWWQ).)*KWWQ$/msg
```

Optimized: (Reduces the number of lookarounds performed)

```
/
   ^ QWWK
   [^KPQ]*+
   (?: (?: K (?!WWQ)
       |   P (?!QXY)
       |   Q (?!WWK)
       )
       [^KPQ]*+
   )*+
   KWWQ $
/xmg
```

Comment: whats the difference between $ (end of line) and \n (newline)  since KWWQ$ and KWWQ\n serves the same purpose

Comment: whats the difference between gms and xms

Comment: `/g` is used to find more than one match. `/x` is allows whitespace to be used meaninglessly in the pattern

Comment: `$` with `/m` matches zero characters at a a newline or at end of string. `\n` matches a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Through some trial and error, I came up with this regex:

```
/^QWWK(?!.*PQXY)(?!.*KWWQ[^\n])(.*?)KWWQ$/gms
```

The `/m` modifier means the input is multi-line and `^` matches the beginning of *any* line and `$` matches the end of *any* line

With the `/s` modifier, the `.` metacharacter means any character *including* newline characters

```
/^QWWK .../m
```

Find a substring that begins with `QWWK` at the start of a line

```
/... KWWQ$/m
```

and ends with `KWWQ` at the end of a line

```
/^QWWK(?!.*PQXY)/s
```

The match fails if `QWWK` is followed by any number of characters (including new lines) and the text `PQXY`.

```
/^QWWK ... (?!.KWWQ[^\n]) ... /s
```

The match also fails if `QWWK` is followed by any number of characters, the text `KWWQ`, and any character that is not a new line.

```
/^QWWK(.*?)KWWQ$/s
```

Put any text between `QWWK` and `KWWQ`, including new lines, in a capture group. Use the non-greedy modifier `?` so that the regexp will not try to capture from an early `QWWK` observation to the latest possible `KWWQ` observation.

Comment: I think `gms` is the key.

Comment: `/^QWWK(.*?)KWWQ$/s` will match `QWWK PQXY KWWQ` and `QWWK QWWK KWWQ`

Comment: `/^QWWK(.*?)KWWQ$/s` is not the whole regexp, just a part of it I separated out for explanation.

Comment: `/^QWWK(?!.*PQXY)(?!.*KWWQ[^\n])(.*?)KWWQ$/gms` is equally broken. Fails against `"QWWK KWWQ\naKWWQb"`

Comment: @mob i  checked in sublime text for "QWWK KWWQ\naKWWQb". `^QWWK(?!.*PQXY)(.*?)KWWQ$` shows the match as `QWWK KWWQ\n` where as with `(?s)^QWWK(?!.*PQXY)(.*?)KWWQ$` nothing is matched. Can you explain the reason. Because irrespective of multiple lines it should match

Answer (score -1):

I read this post [Multiline search replace with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030787/multiline-search-replace-with-perl)

I tried the below and looks to be working:

```
$ perl -0pe 's/^QWWK(?:(?!PQXY).)*?KWWQ\n/sometext/gms' sample.txt > sample_mod.txt
```

Then only condition 4 is replaced and others remain intact

Comment: Slurp mode is `-0777`, not `-0`.

Comment: changed it to `(?!PQXY).)`

Comment: Now it matches the whole of `"QWWK\nQWWK\nKWWQ\n"`, and it probably shouldn't